# Creating a Subdomain for an SFTP site on AWS

Tags: sftp, amazon-web-services

I currently have an sftp site setup on AWS where I can connect via Filezilla by providing the long AWS Public DNS name or the Public IP address(hostname) along with my credentials.

I have an existing domain abc.com which is hosted elsewhere(not aws). I want to use a sub domain such as sftp.abc.com to connect to my sftp site instead of the IP address.

Can I create the subdomain(sftp.abc.com) on AWS using Route53? If so, how do I accomplish this?

Would this affect my primary domain site abc.com ?

Anyone who can give me some advice on this would be helpful. Thanks

Comment: Are you already using Route53 for your DNS?

Comment: Do you understand that DNS only provides loopup support for services like SFTP? So if you would like different servers on `abc.com` and `site.abc.com`, then you'll need two IP addresses. If you are content with different ports or usernames, then there is no need for an alternate domain name.

Comment: SFTP / SSH does not interfere with HTTP / HTTPS

Comment: No.. I'm currently not using Route53 for the DNS. Yes, I would be pointing sitie.abc.com to an IP address. Would the steps mentioned in this article accomplish this?
https://bubinga.co/pointing-subdomain-aws-ec2-instance/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I can connect via Filezilla by providing the long AWS Public DNS name or the Public IP address(hostname) along with my credentials.

DNS maps an domain name to an IP. Subdomains are no different. Therefore it should be possible to map the AWS Public IP to your subdomain with a standard A record in DNS (through whichever provider you use for `abc.com`).

> Can I create the subdomain (sftp.abc.com) on AWS using Route53?

Since you apparently are *not* using Route53 for the DNS of `abc.com` and already have a Public IP through AWS, this is likely not the proper way to go.

> Would the steps mentioned in [this article](https://bubinga.co/pointing-subdomain-aws-ec2-instance/) accomplish this?

The answer is most likely yes.

Comment: Yep It worked. Thanks a ton for the responses.

Comment: Your welcome. Glad it worked. =)